# My Blizzard downloader is stuck

Tags: technical-issues, diablo-iii

So I decided to pre-download Diablo 3 for the release date. My downloader is at 100% and has been for some time. Any idea's on how to unstick it? I tried running the now-complete installer.exe that was downloaded and it's telling me I cannot due to it being in use by another program (likely the downloader).

I'm aware that closing the downloader and then reloading it to resume where it left off and finish whatever last second stuff it has to do is an option, but since its 'stuck' I'm worried something might go wrong.

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck? The Blizzard downloader is a P2P client, even if it has finished downloading it stays open to let others download from you. Check out the button on the lower right, if the download is over it should read "Finished" or something like that.

Comment: @kappei no it reads cancel

Comment: Kill the agent.exe process.  It will restart automatically and should let you proceed.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot thank you that worked! however oddly though. apparently some kind of error had fooled it into thinking I was done and thats why it was stuck. I have 3 gigs left still. Please post as answer and I will accept.

Comment: The downloader is based on BitTorrent, an *extremely robust* protocol for downloading.  It is minimally phased by crashes, disconnections, partially downloaded files being deleted or much else.  Whenever it starts up again it scans through all chunks and if any are wrong/missing it redownloads.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Blizzard Launcher frequently gets stuck.  It will either think it needs updating and never find anything or it will think it is done updating and still need more.  Usually this has something to do with `agent.exe` not initializing properly.

To fix:

- Open your favorite flavor process manager (Crtl+Shift+Esc on Windows)
- Look for `agent.exe` (or `agent.exe * 32` on 64-bit)
- End the `agent.exe` process.

`agent.exe` will then restart itself and the Launcher will come to its senses.

Comment: For amusements sake who is Agent86?

Comment: @Ender - Agent 86 is the main character from the Hitman series.

Comment: @Agent86 is everyone's favorite mod!

Comment: @Ramhound, you're thinking of [Hitman: Code Name 47](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Codename_47).  Agent 86 is a bit, shall we say... [older](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Adams)

Comment: However, Agent 99 could arguably be the real draw of the show...