# Stuck on "Updating setup files..." when installing Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

After a reasonable hiatus from Blizzard games, I have decided to reinstall Diablo 3. I used to have it installed and working on this machine and removed my previous install using Add/Remove Programs. However, now when I try to reinstall the game, the Diablo 3 Setup starts 'Updating setup files...' and then hangs;

[image]

I have had a [quick](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5912813389) [google](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4736524974) for ideas on how to fix it which seems to bring up a bunch of posts when the server loads were really high last year, nevertheless I have been through the list of suggestions, making sure that secondary login is enabled, running the installer as administrator, etc.

After leaving the installer for ~30 minutes, it finally brings up an error stating it could not run the Blizzard agent;

[image]

This gives me an error code - BLZPTS00007 - which gives me a [few more google hits](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4008681895) including a [seemingly official guide on how to troubleshoot agent issues](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battlenet-update-agent-troubleshooting) on Battle.net, however performing the steps listed under 'Advanced Troubleshooting' still hasn't resolved my problem.

How can I get past "Updating setup files..." when reinstalling Diablo 3, and what is error BLZPTS0007?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65601/my-blizzard-downloader-is-stuck

Comment: Killing any of the agent processes that spawn (it spawns many) results in the launcher loading with an immediate error stating "There has been a communication error, please restart the launcher", restarting the launcher results in the process repeating again

Comment: Did you try to remove D3 again, then manually delete all the files associated with it(don't know which ones exactly, but most probably in `My Documents` there will be a folder for D3)? Run `CCleaner` twice, then try it again. If it didn't help maybe there is a problem with the game disk? Try downloading an installer from `Blizzard` website. These were just some wild guesses, so I kept it as a comment

Comment: since it didn't "install" yet - there is no entry in add/remove programs. I have nothing in My Documents, I have the launcher files in C:\ProgramData and I have removed all of those, I have cleared all of my various temporary file locations as per the recommendations, rebooted, ensured that none of the files had returned, etc etc - still doesn't get past that screenshot

Comment: What OS are you running? Windows 7 64bit I presume?

Comment: Windows 8 64 bit - I have previously run Diablo 3 on this machine with this operating system but I had uninstalled it and now I can't reinstall it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, Internet Explorer (which I never use) was set to "work offline". For whatever reason, with Internet Explorer set to work offline, the Diablo 3 installer was failing to do anything other than time out.

I disabled "work offline" by unchecking "Work Offline" in the file menu (available by pressing the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key in newer versions of Windows/Internet Explorer);

[image]

Once this option was disabled, everything worked first time.