# Stuck on "Checking for updates..." when installing World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have recently been demanded to return to World of Warcraft, to take part in a reform of my old guild, so I am trying to reinstall World of Warcraft. I have downloaded the installer with no problems and run it as administrator, however it simply hangs at "Checking for updates..." as per below;

[image]

I have left this installer for a period of time and it has not timed out, it simply just sits there doing nothing. While I was investigating [a similar issue for Diablo 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/117353/27134)
 (which got several steps further than this issue), I have already completely cleaned the World of Warcraft agent from my machine, and rebooted multiple times in an attempt to get this installation process to progress.

I did some additional googling and [found a post on a blue tracker](http://blues.wowraider.net/blue/us2/6413174065/Stuck-on-checking-for-updates...) which simply advises to perform all of the steps I have already run through.

Comment: Maybe blizzard just doesn't like you?

Comment: You'd think after the amount of money I've given them over the years, they'd be jumping for joy at my return...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, Internet Explorer (which I never use) was set to "work offline". For whatever reason, with Internet Explorer set to work offline, the Diablo 3 installer was failing to do anything other than time out.

I disabled "work offline" by unchecking "Work Offline" in the file menu (available by pressing the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key in newer versions of Windows/Internet Explorer);

[image]

Once this option was disabled, everything worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your behind a router you should make sure that the ports are set as recommended by Blizzard.

Follow this link for a complete list of ports:
https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/firewall-configuration-for-blizzard-games

Second of all, I assume you are rejoining in the Mist of Panderia expantion.
The installer should be the latest including Mist of Panderia.
Any update search should be done via the Blizzard Launcher menu.
In this menu you can enable the option "peer-to-peer".

If this does not work, you should try re-installing the game with the latest installer file. (should be like 40 mb., and then the game will download and install via the Blizzard Launcher)

If this does not work - you should contact Blizzard technical support.

Comment: I'm not getting as far as the launcher - the screen in my screenshot is the first stage of *getting* to the launcher, and was downloaded lastnight. Additionally, I dial up using PPPOE so there is no router between me and the internet, I briefly disabled my firewall for additional testing but there is no way that I'm leaving that off when I'm connected directly to the internet.

Comment: @kalina Did you download the launcher directly from your own WoW page? (Where you can see your active games - you can choose to "download game client") If none of this works, I would borrow the old installer via DVD or CD, and install the basic game, and thereby update it. (takes long) Do ofcause contact Blizzard techincal support first!!!

Comment: yes - logged into battle.net, clicked my wow account, clicked install/reinstall client, selected windows, downloaded the file, ran the file, waited for some time, took a screenshot, raised the question

Comment: An alternative could be to try to run windows in safe mode and installing it from here: http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/start-your-computer-in-safe-mode If this does not work, try to repeat the download of the game client. If not working, see if you the old installation discs or if you can borrow them. Otherwice, make a support ticket I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, provided by a Blizz Admin

http://battle.net/support/article/deleting-the-battlenet-cache-folder-windows

Basically: close all Battle.net programs, then delete whichever of the following exists:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Blizzard Entertainment\
C:\ProgramData\Blizzard Entertainment\
/Users/Shared/Blizzard/Battle.net/
```

Comment: Could you quote the appropriate text in your post?  While it would be nice to assume that battle.net and indeed that support article will always co-exist with World of Warcraft, it is bad practice to assume so.